# How to add transparency/alpha (material) value slider + viewport color

Tags: interface, 3d-view

Sofar I replicated all the needed shading tools for an object inside the tool shelve.

[image]

The transparency function however only makes sense when the UI also allows you to change the alpha value which is part of the material menu

[image]

This is the code I have sofar:

```
class ObjectShading(bpy.types.Panel):
bl_label = "Shading"
bl_idname = "ObjectShading"
bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
bl_category = "Claas"

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    obj = context.object
    mesh = obj.data

    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="AutoEdgeBreak:")
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(mesh, "use_auto_smooth", text="BreakEdge")
    row.active = mesh.use_auto_smooth and not mesh.has_custom_normals
    row.prop(mesh, "auto_smooth_angle", text="Angle")
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="ManualSmooth:")
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("object.shade_smooth", text="Smooth", icon="SMOOTHCURVE")
    row.operator("object.shade_flat", text="Sharp", icon="LINCURVE")
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(obj, "draw_type", text="Draw Type")
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(obj, "show_wire", text="Wire")
    row.prop(obj, "show_transparent", text="Transparency")
    row.prop(obj, "show_x_ray", text="X-Ray")
```

Looking into UI.py I discovered this but I fail to figure out how I could extract the proper code to add to my script so it only renders the viewport color and alpha slider.

```
class CyclesMaterial_PT_settings(CyclesButtonsPanel, Panel):
bl_label = "Settings"
bl_context = "material"
bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return context.material and CyclesButtonsPanel.poll(context)

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    mat = context.material
    cmat = mat.cycles

    split = layout.split()
    col = split.column()
    col.label(text="Surface:")
    col.prop(cmat, "sample_as_light", text="Multiple Importance")
    col.prop(cmat, "use_transparent_shadow")

    col = split.column()
    col.label(text="Volume:")
    sub = col.column()
    sub.active = use_cpu(context)
    sub.prop(cmat, "volume_sampling", text="")
    sub.prop(cmat, "volume_interpolation", text="")
    col.prop(cmat, "homogeneous_volume", text="Homogeneous")

    layout.separator()
    split = layout.split()

    col = split.column(align=True)
    col.label("Viewport Color:")
    col.prop(mat, "diffuse_color", text="")
    col.prop(mat, "alpha")

    col.separator()
    col.label("Viewport Alpha:")
    col.prop(mat.game_settings, "alpha_blend", text="")

    col = split.column(align=True)
    col.label("Viewport Specular:")
    col.prop(mat, "specular_color", text="")
    col.prop(mat, "specular_hardness", text="Hardness")

    col.separator()
    col.prop(mat, "pass_index")
```

Adding the code

```
row.prop(mat, "alpha")
```

results into an error code stating that "mat" is not defined which makes sense.

So when I then add add the mat definition after the def command

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    obj = context.object
    mesh = obj.data
    mat = context.material
    cmat = mat.cycles
```

I get this error and I dont understand this and what cases this. I just copied the code.

location: :-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\untitled.blend\Claas_UI_2.py", line 98, in draw
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'material'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context contains the current state within blender, eg `bpy.context.selected_objects` is a list of the selected objects while `bpy.context.active_object` is the active object.

While you can have an active material selected, every object can have their own active material, so it is an object property not a global context property. So in your example you want to use -

```
obj = context.object
mesh = obj.data
mat = obj.active_material
cmat = mat.cycles
```

Comment: This worked perfect!